# Página apresenta erro em Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

peguei uma página para manutenção e notei o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Suspeito que os diretórios do angular devem estar incorretos, porém mesmo ao trocá-los e colocar o link pego na internet (CDN) aparentemente não funcionou. Essas variáveis à esquerda deveriam ser preenchidas!

Baixei os arquivos CDN e coloquei no meu servidor:

```
<script src="js/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bower_components/angular-input-masks/angular-input-masks-dependencies.js"></script>
<script src="js/bower_components/angular-input-masks/angular-input-masks.js"></script>
```

Alguém sabe o que pode me ajudar a resolver isso?!

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Parcelamento boletos</title>
    <!--Ajax Libs-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-i18n/1.6.6/angular-locale_pt-br.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
    <!--Bootstrap e estilo Libs-->
    <script src="js/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open Sans|Ropa Sans|Source Sans Pro|Oxygen Mono|Inconsolata|Droid+Sans|Telex' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="js/bower_components/br_format.js"></script>
    <!--Angular Libs-->
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bower_components/angular-input-masks/angular-input-masks-dependencies.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bower_components/angular-input-masks/angular-input-masks.js"></script>
    <!--Scripts Personalizados-->
    <script src="config/plugins/parcela_pagamento.js?random=<?php echo rand(); ?>"></script>

</head>
<script>
    var contrato_id = <?= $_GET['id']; ?>;
</script>
<body ng-controller="parcelaCtrl">
<div class="container jumbotron" style="height: 1000px;">
    <form name="parcelaBoleto">
    <div class="row text-center">
        Cliente {{contrato.nome}} Id({{contrato.id}})
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4" style="text-align: right;">
                <label for="desconto">Valor</label>
                <br> {{contrato.valor | currency}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2" style="text-align: left;">
                <label for="desconto">Parcela/Desconto</label>
                <div class="row">
                    <select name="desconto" id="desconto" class="form-control"
                            ng-options='o as (o.parcelas +"x / %"+ o.desconto) for o in tipo_desconto'
                            ng-model="descont_type" ng-change="simulate(descont_type)">
                        <option value="">Selecione o pagamento</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="false" class="col-xs-4 form-group" style="text-align: left;">
                <label for="desconto_manual"> Desconto ou Acrescimo Manual</label>

                <input type="number" id="desconto_manual" class="form-control"
                       ng-disabled="!descont_type" ng-model="desconto_manual" ng-change="simulate(descont_type)">
                ACRESC MAX( {{ desconto_minimo| currency }}) DESC MAX({{desconto_maximo | currency }})
                <p ng-show="parcelaBoleto.desconto_manual.$error.nginvalid"> Valor De desconto invalido.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="!enableSumbmit">
            <div class="alert-danger" style="margin-left: 40%; margin-right: 40%;">
                Valor nao pode ser lancado. Provavel Desconto Invalido.
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" ng-if="enableSumbmit">
            O valor original e de {{valor_total | currency}} <br>
            Adicionado ao desconto concedido pelo adiantamento {{desconto_padrao | currency }}<br><br>
            O cliente pagara um valor unico de {{valor_com_desconto | currency}} equivalente as {{parcelas}}
            parcelas<br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <a ng-click="confirm()" class="btn btn-success center-block" ng-disabled="check_confirm()" ng-if="hide_confirm"
               style="margin-left: 30%; margin-right: 30%;">Confirmar Lancamento de boleto</a>
        </div>

        <div class="text-center" ng-if="msg_de_retorno.confirma" style="margin-right: 30%; margin-bottom: 10%; margin-left: 30%;">
            <div class="row" ng-if="msg_de_retorno.success">
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    {{msg_de_retorno.msg}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" ng-if="!msg_de_retorno.success">
                <div class="alert-danger">{{msg_de_retorno.msg}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: difícil ajudar sem ver o código.. pode ser um erro no modulo, controller, referência, muitas coisas
coloque seu código js/html na pergunta

Comment: Inseri o script html que gera a página do print! A parte js tem muita informação particular, mas estava funcionando corretamente antes, não mexi nela... Se tiver alguma ideia...

Comment: usando a ferramenta do navegador consegue ver se todos os scripts foram carregados? não vi no seu html uma referência para um arquivo .js onde deve ter a controller "parcelaCtrl"

Comment: Essa controller está no script `parcela_pagamento.js`

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at angular-input-masks.js:3` isso está sendo mostrado no navegador, pode estar influenciando?

Comment: pode estar, ele pode estar parando a execução
foi incluido recentemente esse modulo? adicionou a referência dele no modules do angular?

Comment: Acho que consegui resolver! Troquei ele pelo `angular-input-masks-standalone.min.js` conforme https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks. O erro sumiu e a página ficou com os dados vazios... Agora irei verificar alguns exemplos pra ver se está funcionando corretamente!

Comment: legal boa... as vezes um erro ao carregar um script quebra tudo

Comment: É que sou iniciante em Angular, peguei isso pra arrumar sem nunca ter mexido... Só uso Jquery puro e Ajax. Obrigado pelo auxílio!